# Was the term "Quadrant" invented for Star Trek

Tags: star-trek

I hear the term *Quadrant* get used to describe how the galaxy is divided up so I am wondering if the division of our galaxy into quadrants was actually coined first in *Star Trek* or if it was something that existed beforehand?

If it was invented in *Star Trek* then who invented the term? Humans? Vulcans who taught humans it after first contact? How is it species in the Delta Quadrant like the Kazon know of this if it's a Federation term?

Comment: "Delta quadrant" is the closest translation the universal translator can provide for whatever the Kazon are really saying.

Comment: Since the line between the Alpha and Beta Quadrants runs directly through the Earth's solar system, I feel safe in saying that the system was probably designed by a Human.

Comment: @chepner: Of all the magic things that the UT does, I continue to find this one of the most impressive. The UT knows how every species maps and subdivides the galaxy! Awesome sauce.

Comment: Well, that's why I said "closest" :) I read somewhere long ago that the UT basically maps brainwaves from the speaker (never mind how it works in anything other than face-to-face communication, and never mind that the underlying neurology of speech has to be the same in every species), so I assume a reference to any  large-enough region of space gets mapped to the appropriate "quadrant" in English.

Comment: Asked on ELU, this would've been closed for lack of [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant).

Comment: Note that *sector* also predates sci-fi.

Comment: @Mazura if the answer is in the first search result it should be general reference on every SE....

Answer (score 55):

No. A galactic quadrant is a division in astronomy, using the Sun as the pole of the mapping system.

Star Trek borrowed this, although they used their own mapping system.

You can find more information about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_quadrant

Comment: There's no indication (from that link) of whether this system pre-dates the one used in Star Trek.

Comment: A linked article references a 1960 paper's summarised findings about dividing the galaxy into 90-degree separated regions, although I didn't spot it using the word *quadrant* explicitly (http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1960MNRAS.121..123B). The earliest explicit reference I can find is from 1997, which post-dates TNG (http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/312965).

Comment: The Oxford English dictionary's earliest citation for this astronomical use of quadrant is from Newton in 1702.

Comment: Stanislaw Lem used the term "quadrant" to discribe a position of a spaceship in his novel "The Test" first published in 1959. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Pirx_the_Pilot  Though I never read it in the original language, I do not think it first apeared in translation.

Comment: @Ols Original is: *"Główna do Albatrosa cztery Aresterra, tankowanie **kwadrant** siódmy. Omega Główna, tankowanie przeniesione Omega Główna. Koniec."* So it's exactly "quadrant". Although it's "seventh quadrant" so I can't make any sense out of it except being "space lingo". Or perhaps in 2d there are 4 quadrants but in 3d there are 8.

Comment: @Agent In this novel quadrant is a 1/8 of a sphere. There are 4 quadrants in the upper semisphere and 4 in the lower.

Comment: @Buzz, the quadrant Newton is referring to is an astronomical instrument, basically a quarter of a circle with either a plumbbob or a movable plate. It is used for measuring the angle of objects, similar to an astrolabe (which is typically a complete circle) or sextant. It is unrelated to galactic coordinates - Newton didn't even know the Milky Way WAS a galaxy, after all.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: Newton didn’t know the Milky Way was a galaxy, but he certainly could have considered the division of the sky (or any geometric area/volume) into *quadrants* in the sense of 90°-delineated regions.

Comment: @Agent_L In technical terms, that should be an *octant;* there are 8 octants in 3D, just like there are 4 quadrants in 2D.

Comment: Based upon the ways I heard 'quadrant' used in the shows I am not convinced, despite its appearence in the linked Wikpedia article, that the scriptwriters intended 'quadrant' to mean one of four regions of space divided in this Earth-oriented way.  Star Trek has a long history of [technobabble](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Technobabble) and this may be just another vague term they used because it sounded cool.

Comment: @Angew Yeah, but the galaxy is pretty much flat. There's no reason to use octants to subdivide something with so little "height" - the Milky way is about a hundred times more wide than it is high; it'd be more ridiculous than using octants to describe the position of players on a football field :)

Comment: @Luaan Of course. I was just addressing whether in 3d, there are 8 quadrants or what. Not in relation to the question at hand.

Comment: @PLL Newton certainly knew that the Milky Way was a galaxy, as that was the original meaning of "galaxy", a Greek term which was translated into English as "Milky Way". What he didn't know was that there were **other** "galaxies".

Comment: @spencer - correct, they did not use galactic quadrant as defined by that wikipedia article.  they took the term, and gave it its own definition.  primarily, they simplified it and shifted the pole to the galactic centre.

Answer (score 43):

"Quadrant" is a term used by mathematicians to refer to a section of the plane, as in "the positive x-y quadrant."  I personally encountered that term as an undergraduate in the 80s, before STTNG came out.  Astronomers also use the term to refer to sections of the sky as viewed from Earth, and also as sections of the galaxy.

I don't have any sources handy, but I think mathematicians have been using the term for centuries, since Renee Decartes invented Cartesian coordinates in the 17th century.

Comment: That's the right answer here. It's a mathematical term for centuries. Unfortunately I'm short of sources ATM.

Comment: Note "quadrant" comes from "quad", meaning "four". A quadrant is 1/4 of a plane. In Cartesian co-ordinates, there is positive X/positive Y, positive X/negative Y, negative X/positive Y, and negative X/negative Y.

Comment: Exactly. In Star Trek a cartesian two-dimensional coordinate system was placed on the most common top-down view on the milky way (which is logical, as the bulk of the visible matter in the milky way extends much more in width and length then in height), with the origin placed on the galactic center and apparently the division of 1st and 2nd quadrant placed through the solar system. Instead of labeling the quadrants 1 to 4 they are labeled with greek letters and normally it is displayed with a rotation of 180°.

Answer (score 21):

The word "quadrant" roughly means 1/4th and comes from Latin. It was recorded at least as long ago as 1400. It's especially used to denote a 1/4 section of a circle. A pizza traditionally cut in 4 parts is excellent example of quadrants, but the term is most often used in geography and astronomy. There even is an [astronomical instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(instrument)) called "quadrant" which is used to measure angles, unsurprisingly, up to 90 degrees (one quadrant). It also looks like 1/4 of a circle.

So the term is older than Star Trek and modern English.

//edit: Quadrant is a 2d term. In 3d often space is first divided in half and then each half into quadrants, which results in 8 quadrants making a whole.

Comment: If it's divided into 8 parts, they're octants, not quadrants.

Comment: @MontyHarder True, but being originally developed from upon a planet's surface, where you can only see 4 of the octants at a time, it's natural that they would only be called quadrants.

Comment: Mmmh, I'm fairly sure that if you go to a *pizzeria* (an Italian term for restaurants serving mostly pizza) and ask for a "quadrant of pizza" they'll stare at you as you were a sick Klingon barfing in the middle of the room (at least here in Italy :-).

Comment: @MontyHarder The Milky Way is 2-dimensional in the practical sense of starship travel. Because our galaxy is at least 50x as wide as it is deep, any starship able to travel the width or span of the quadrant will be able to travel to any point within the depth of the quadrant, too.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati: fun fact: *pizzeria* is widely used in North America to mean the same thing.  I didn't know (until just now) that it was borrowed unmodified from real Italian, and wasn't just an Italian-sounding name for pizza places!  It's used equally to describe a fancy pizza restaurant with gourmet pizzas, or a cheap take-out / delivery (like a Pizza Hut, or any local non-fancy independent pizzeria, many of which serve delicious pizzas).  English culture often likes to keep the foreign names for food, because it sounds exotic.  As long as it's easily pronounceable for English speakers.

Comment: @MontyHarder I think that's because quadrant got a strong connotation to "90 deg angle". But I agree with octant being the better term here, that's why I commented "how can there be a 7th quadrant" on the other question.

Comment: @PeterCordes I like to pronounce cafeteria as if it were an Italian word, in the same sense as pizzeria or trattoria (the latter being a more modest establishment than a ristorante). No Italians have complained yet.

Comment: @PeterCordes Actually it is an Italian term, but it isn't usually used to indicate only restaurants, also low-end ones, but not cheap take-outs. An Italian wouldn't normally refer to these latter as "pizzerie" (plural of "pizzeria").

Comment: @SpehroPefhany "Trattoria" is a fairly common Italian word, but it doesn't necessarily describe the fact it is more modest than a restaurant (at least from a price point of view - there are "trattorie" that "skin you alive", as some Italian would say :-) The term refers to shops that have a more informal setting than restaurants, usually serving dishes from the local tradition of the zone where they are located.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati: I'm not 100% sure about typical usage in English.  Now that I think about it, I think "pizzeria" in North American English is not commonly used to describe cheap takeout or sold-by-the-slice places, only places that at least have some eat-in seating for a pizza that they make for you after you choose toppings from a menu (such places often also deliver and do take-out).  Of course, terms do get mis-used sometimes by some people, but I think common usage in English does mostly match what you describe.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany "Cafeteria" is not an Italian word, though. The Italian word from which is derived is "caffetteria", but it means something slightly different in Italy: it is not a shop in itself, but it indicates a room in a bigger building, where coffee and other food are served for small and quick meals, usually for breakfast. For example in an Hotel you could have the dining room separated from the "caffetteria" (it's a sort of internal bar, if you want). The same term is sometimes used for the internal bar of train and bus stations, but it is not very common nowadays.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany "Caffetteria" is also used to indicate the internal bar of some "non commercial" building, for example a company building, a university building. Even in some military quarter there is a room sometimes called "caffetteria" where military people can get some fast food and drink when off-duty (the term is most used for officers quarters, for troops the same room is often called "spaccio", which is very specific for that situation).

Comment: @Lorenzo: That is mostly how "cafeteria" is used in English.  It's different from a French-style "cafe" (shop that serves hot drinks, pastries, muffins, etc).  It does mean pretty much what you describe: a room where you can get food (or eat your own food) in a large (often institutional) building.  However, it's most often associated with lunch meals, because that's the meal eaten in the middle of the work/school day.  In a university student residence, the cafeteria will be open for all three meals.  You don't place an order, you line up with a tray at a counter for food.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cafeteria has some pictures, also points "Cafeterias are different from coffeehouses, despite being the Spanish translation of the English term".  One difference from Italian is that I don't think cafeteria has ever applied to train station or bus station bars.  BTW, another difference from other food service is that a cafeteria often has a flat price for a meal, instead of paying based on what you chose.  So they only have to charge for admission at the door.  Surprisingly interesting to talk about this, BTW :P

Answer (score 1):

Using Search Star Trek Scripts, I find there are 415 uses of "sector", usually to mean a volume of space containing several star systems, in *Star Trek* up to and including *Enterprise*.

In TOS (1966-1969) and the TOS movies "sector" is used 41 times, usually to mean a volume of space containing several star systems but sometimes to mean a section of a planetary surface, etc.  It was also used to describe a sector of interstellar space 6 times in TAS (1973-74).

There are 19 uses of the word "quadrant" in TOS (1966-1969).  It can mean a section of the ship or a section of a planet's surface.  But it is mostly used to mean a volume of interstellar space containing several star systems.

This use was most notorious in "The Trouble With Tribbles":

> KORAX: Of course, I'd say that Captain Kirk deserves his ship. We like the Enterprise. We, we really do. That sagging old rust bucket is designed like a garbage scow. Half the quadrant knows it. That's why they're learning to speak Klingonese.

"Quadrant" is also used 3 times in TAS (1973-1974) to mean a volume of interstellar space containing several star systems.

TOS and TAS do not specify whether sectors and quadrants are different names for the same thing or different sized volumes of space.  Quadrants are "fourths" but they don't have to be "fourths" of sectors.  It is possible that TOS quadrants are fourths of TOS sectors. It is possible that TOS sectors are parts of quadrants that are parts of still larger volumes of space.

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Quadrant[1](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Quadrant)

It was not until the TNG episode "The Price" 13 November 1989, that *Star Trek* started the present system of dividing the entire galaxy into four vast quadrants many times larger than TOS era quadrants.

TOS didn't invent the use of sectors or quadrants for volumes of interstellar space.  James White's "Sector General" series is set in a giant hospital space Station, sector Twelve General Hospital, began in the November 1957 issue of *New Worlds* magazine.

In the military a sector is

> SECTOR— A clearly defined area that a given unit
>   protects or covers with fire.
>
> SECTOR OF FIRE— A section of terrain designated by
>   boundaries that is assigned to a unit or to a weapon
>   to cover by fire.

https://www.mhawisconsin.org/Data/Sites/1/media/Veterans/common_military_terms.pdf[2](https://www.mhawisconsin.org/Data/Sites/1/media/Veterans/common_military_terms.pdf)

The military use of "sector" for a geographical area may have suggested the sciecne fiction use of "sector" for a galactographical volume.

Ras Ryman (James D. Brown) published *The Quadrant War* (1976) "a space opera of war between rival interstellar empires".

http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/ryman_ras[3](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/ryman_ras[2])

This was after TOS, but quadrants of space are mentioned in James Blish *A Life For The Stars* (1962,1963).  In Chapter Four "Schoolroom in the Sky" the history of the space cities mentions quadrants of space two times.

[What Was the First Science Fiction Use of Space Quadrants?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184333/what-was-the-first-science-fiction-use-of-space-quadrants)[4](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184333/what-was-the-first-science-fiction-use-of-space-quadrants)

[What was the first Science Fiction use of Space Sectors?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184331/what-was-the-first-science-fiction-use-of-space-sectors)[5](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184331/what-was-the-first-science-fiction-use-of-space-sectors)

Answer (score -1):

No.  It also appears in math (specifically graphing). The only reason I know this is because of Math class today.

Comment: This answer adds nothing that is not already in other answers.